# Deletion of records selected by select query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a select query like this:

```
SELECT ji . * , a.acc_name
FROM zp_journal_info ji
INNER JOIN zp_account a ON a.id = ji.account_id
WHERE ji.date_time LIKE '2013-03-19%'
ORDER BY ji.id ASC
```

I don't know anything about the rest of the database since I didn't develop it but I just need to delete the rows that are generated by the above query. Would the query below do this correctly?

```
DELETE
FROM zp_journal_info ji
INNER JOIN zp_account a ON a.id = ji.account_id
WHERE ji.date_time LIKE '2013-03-19%'
ORDER BY ji.id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the table name on where the deletion of record takes place.

```
DELETE ji
FROM   zp_journal_info ji
       INNER JOIN zp_account a ON a.id = ji.account_id
WHERE  ji.date_time LIKE '2013-03-19%'
```

you can also use `DATE`

```
DELETE ji
FROM   zp_journal_info ji
       INNER JOIN zp_account a ON a.id = ji.account_id
WHERE  DATE(ji.date_time) = '2013-03-19'
```

Comment: but what if i need to delete the *entire* entries that come out of the select query, i.e. across both tables?